# LAMP Server 100% CPU Usage from 5 WP sites

Tags: linux, wordpress, lamp, cpu-usage

I have a server hosted in Google Cloud configured to serve websites on the LAMP stack. Current, all of these websites are WordPress-based, of which there are only 5.

I have an `n1-standard-1` server so it has 1 vCPU and 3.75 GB memory. This should be plenty, given the sites on the server have a small load (read: visitor count).

Now, the CPU is nearly always at, or above, 100%. See image.

[image: CPU usage of server]

The server uses `mpm_prefork` and the configuration is shown below:

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers                    2
    MinSpareServers                 2
    MaxSpareServers                 5
    MaxRequestWorkers               50
    ServerLimit                     50
    MaxConnectionsPerChild          0
</IfModule>
```

When I restart `apache2`, the following errors always appear in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`:

```
[Mon Jun 06 15:01:58.204747 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 18177] AH00163: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jun 06 15:01:58.204791 2016] [core:notice] [pid 18177] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Jun 06 15:02:18.815485 2016] [mpm_prefork:error] [pid 18177] AH00161: server reached MaxRequestWorkers setting, consider raising the MaxRequestWorkers setting
```

At which point running `htop`, I see 50 threads have spun up each with CPU usage at ~2% (range is 1.9% - 2.9% but most are at 1.9% or 2.0%). I am certain there is not a heavy load from visitor traffic at this time - if ever, in fact.

However, on another server I use of almost an identical nature but for a different company, I see only a handful of apache2 thread in `htop`, each using nearly no CPU. This other server has no issues and serves traffic just fine.

So I am led to believe something is using up all of the resources on this first machine - either malware or application-level stuff such as a WP plugin.

So, my question is:

How can I go about seeing what is causing this issue, specifically? The issue being the 100%+ CPU usage by the apache2 threads alone.

I speculate there is a plugin causing issues, e.g. a caching plugin or image manipulation plugin or something like that, that is CPU-heavy. I can supply a full list of plugins, if helpful, but how can I work from the server-level up, instead of the application-level down?

Edit:

See top output image:

[image: output from top command]

Looking into XML-RPC attacks, I see some 2000 errors around the All In One WP Security plugin. I guess this is where I can start to look for issues. I'll ask something new if I required and if I can be more specific. Thanks

Comment: Similar has been answered recently, read the Wordpress answers. Key things to look at include XML-RPC attacks, lack of caching (ideally done at the web server level, not in PHP). Post your top/htop output.

Comment: As Tim said: 2 acronyms and a word: XML-RPC attacks.

Comment: Thanks Tim and David. I've updated my question and will look into my issues from here

Comment: Try plugins "Disable JSON API" and "Disable XML-RPC". Your top output is virtually unreadable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the site had been migrated from another server and the old server was left on.

The old server was calling `wp-cron.php` some 10 times per second *by the domain name* and hence calling the new server.

This was causing massive CPU usage.

I turned off the old server.

Comment: Please accept your answer, to prevent people coming into the question to try to help.